# How to make my date field show up in a view?

Tags: 7, views, datetime

I have a content type "Appointment" that has a date field. I collect end dates in that field as well. I have to create a view that lists the appointments in the system. When I add the "appointment date" field to my view, the field does not show up. This is my view exported.

```
$view = new view();
$view->name = 'doctor_appointments';
$view->description = '';
$view->tag = 'default';
$view->base_table = 'node';
$view->human_name = 'Doctor Appointments';
$view->core = 7;
$view->api_version = '3.0';
$view->disabled = FALSE; /* Edit this to true to make a default view disabled initially */

/* Display: Master */
$handler = $view->new_display('default', 'Master', 'default');
$handler->display->display_options['title'] = 'Doctor Appointments';
$handler->display->display_options['use_more_always'] = FALSE;
$handler->display->display_options['access']['type'] = 'perm';
$handler->display->display_options['cache']['type'] = 'none';
$handler->display->display_options['query']['type'] = 'views_query';
$handler->display->display_options['exposed_form']['type'] = 'basic';
$handler->display->display_options['pager']['type'] = 'full';
$handler->display->display_options['pager']['options']['items_per_page'] = '10';
$handler->display->display_options['style_plugin'] = 'default';
$handler->display->display_options['row_plugin'] = 'fields';
/* Field: Content: Nid */
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['nid']['id'] = 'nid';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['nid']['table'] = 'node';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['nid']['field'] = 'nid';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['nid']['label'] = '';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['nid']['exclude'] = TRUE;
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['nid']['element_label_colon'] = FALSE;
/* Field: Content: Title */
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['title']['id'] = 'title';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['title']['table'] = 'node';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['title']['field'] = 'title';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['title']['alter']['word_boundary'] = FALSE;
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['title']['alter']['ellipsis'] = FALSE;
/* Field: Content: Appointment Date */
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['appointment_date']['id'] = 'appointment_date';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['appointment_date']['table'] = 'field_data_appointment_date';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['appointment_date']['field'] = 'appointment_date';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['appointment_date']['label'] = 'Date';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['appointment_date']['element_label_colon'] = FALSE;
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['appointment_date']['settings'] = array(
  'format_type' => 'medium',
  'fromto' => 'both',
  'multiple_number' => '',
  'multiple_from' => '',
  'multiple_to' => '',
  'show_remaining_days' => 0,
  'show_repeat_rule' => 'show',
  'field_formatter_class' => '',
);
/* Field: Content: Appointment Approve */
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['rules_link_appointment_approve']['id'] = 'rules_link_appointment_approve';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['rules_link_appointment_approve']['table'] = 'views_entity_node';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['rules_link_appointment_approve']['field'] = 'rules_link_appointment_approve';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['rules_link_appointment_approve']['rules_link'] = array(
  'rules_link_parameters' => '',
  'rules_link_rewrite' => '',
);
/* Sort criterion: Content: Post date */
$handler->display->display_options['sorts']['created']['id'] = 'created';
$handler->display->display_options['sorts']['created']['table'] = 'node';
$handler->display->display_options['sorts']['created']['field'] = 'created';
$handler->display->display_options['sorts']['created']['order'] = 'DESC';
/* Filter criterion: Content: Published */
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['status']['id'] = 'status';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['status']['table'] = 'node';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['status']['field'] = 'status';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['status']['value'] = 1;
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['status']['group'] = 1;
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['status']['expose']['operator'] = FALSE;
/* Filter criterion: Content: Type */
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['type']['id'] = 'type';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['type']['table'] = 'node';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['type']['field'] = 'type';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['type']['value'] = array(
  'appointment' => 'appointment',
);

/* Display: Page */
$handler = $view->new_display('page', 'Page', 'page');
$handler->display->display_options['path'] = 'doctor-appointments';
```

I am using:

- Views version 7.x-3.14
- Date Views version 7.x-2.9
- Date version 7.x-2.9

Please let me know how to get the date field display in a view.

Comment: A screenshot of your view, date field settings and view preview would be way more helpful than the export code.

Comment: Does it not show up at all - for example as table column - or is it not displaying any value? Did you try different formatters in your view for the field? Did you double check the field name used?